# How can I get VSCode + Flake8 to use tabs?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flake8

`.vscode/settings.json`

```json
{
    ...
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
}
```

I have the following config with linting with flake8. However, I see no options for flake8 to use tabs in my python project. I found [flake8-tabs](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-tabs/#use-flake8-tabs) and attempted to configure it with VS Code to get it to work:

```
[flake8]
use-flake8-tabs = true
```

Comment: By default installing flake8-tabs will only enable the blank line indentation checker. To enable flake8-tabs for your project proper, you will need to set the use-flake8-tabs option mentioned below to true. You can refer to the [flake8's docs](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#configuration-locations) to set it.

Comment: I attempted to configure flake8 but the changes didnt apply to vscode. I also have my interpreter correctly configured with poetry.